# How do I check what `origin` references in my remote repository?

Tags: git, git-reset, git-refspec

For as long as I used `git`, if I want to reset my local branch to the remote master branch, I've done

```
git reset --hard origin
```

and this seems to work empirically, but I recently learned that this might be dependent on the settings of the repository and `origin` may not always be the head of the remote master branch.

How can I check what its pointing to?

Comment: you should just use `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: @UpAndAdam that won't reset it to remote master unless you do a fetch prior to that

Comment: @roulette01 yes, a `git fetch` is always required to update the local remote-tracking branches. `git reset --hard origin` requires a fetch too (both commands are identical if `origin/HEAD` is configured as `origin/master`)

Comment: You might consider `git reset --hard @{u}`

Answer (score 3):

Each remote has a *default branch* that can be set with [`git remote set-head`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-headem). This setting is local to your clone and independent from the remote repository (but you can tell Git to assign the value from the remote).

When used in the place of a revision, `origin` is equivalent to `origin/HEAD`. Subsequently, `git reset --hard origin` is identical to `git reset --hard origin/HEAD`.

To query which branch is currently configured as default branch for the remote, run `git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.

To find the configured default branch of the remote repository, run `git remote show origin`. The default branch is printed in the line `HEAD branch: ...`.

Comment: running that command gives me `refs/remotes/origin/master`. this is remote master right, and not `origin/master`?

Comment: @roulette01 `refs/remotes/origin/master` is the full name of the remote-tracking branch `origin/master`. Both forms are equivalent: `git rev-parse origin/master` and `git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master` resolve to the same commit. Similar to how `refs/heads/master` is the full name of `master`.

Comment: Upvoted you for going above and beyond adding some porcelain commands that I found interesting (symbolic-ref) and you mentioned the configured default branch of the remote repository which I also overlooked.  Thanks for also pointing out to OP his comment about fetch was incredibly short sighted.

Comment: This is pretty convenient. I just renamed `origin` to `o` so that I can do `git rebase o` to keep up to date with our main branch. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what `origin` refers to, the best way (IMO) is probably:

```
git config remote.origin.url
```

Note that this says nothing at all about whether the current branch is tracking a branch on `origin`, and `git reset --hard origin` may not at all be what you want.  But I suspect you don't actually care what `origin` is pointing to.  If you want to reset your current branch to be at whatever it is tracking, you can use:

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

which will reset the current branch to its remote tracking branch, and you don't care what the remote `origin` is.  (Note that this actually sets the current branch to what your local repo thinks is current on the remote, so you may need to precede this with a `git fetch`.)

Answer (score 1):

`origin`, by itself, typically refers to a specific remote - the one from which you cloned the repository. If you see `origin` as part of a longer string, like `origin/main` or `origin/develop`, then it indicates that Git should check what it knows of a specified branch (in the examples, `main` or `develop`) as they are on the `origin` remote.

In the specific example you listed (`git reset --hard origin`), your local branch will be reset to what Git knows of the associated remote branch. This is only possible because your local Git already knows that your current branch should track a specific remote branch. (Note that `git reset` does not initiate a network session of any kind, so if you haven't run `git fetch` or `git pull` lately then your reset may not match what's actually on the remote.)

You can see what `origin` refers to with `git remote -v` (which will also list any other remotes) or with `git remote get-url origin` (which will only list origin).

Answer (score 1):

You can see what origin references in your repository with `git remote -v`

However a simple fix of your command would solve your problem separately. Just use `git reset --hard origin/master` and be explicit that you want to reset to `origin/master`. (Note that for highest accuracy you should probably do a `git fetch origin` first.)

In your case, it only works because your branch is tracking `origin/master` so git is selecting the remote tracking branch from `origin` for you as the implied refspec (fully expanded as `origin/master`).  If you were not tracking `origin/master` that would not reset to `origin/master` but to `origin/foo` if you were tracking the remote repo's `foo` branch for example.

Comment: hmm i think you need to precede `git reset --hard origin/master` with a `git fetch`, because `origin/master` may not be up to date with remote master

Comment: @roulette01 yes, you need `git fetch`, but that's a given. Even with `origin` (that is `origin/HEAD`), you need a prior `git fetch`. Remote-tracking branches are only updated when told so explicitly; they are never updated "behind the scenes".

Answer (score 1):

`git remote -v` will show all referenced remote branchs of a local repository. the name is a `variable`, you can set any whatever you want.

Beside, you can change the `variable`:

```
git remote add origin https://some_url/some_repo
```

or remove it:

```
git remote remove origin
```

And use other name, after removing:

```
git remote set-url blabla https://some_url/some_repo
```

Lastly, you can reset: `variable` is origin and `current branch` is master

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```